# Restoring Database from Azure Blob Storage failing from SSMS while using RESTORE FILELISTONLY

Tags: azure

I am trying to restore a  SQL 2016 database backup file which is in Azure Blob Storage from SSMS using the below T- SQL command :

*RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM URL = 'https://.blob.core.windows.net//.bak'
GO*

It works fine with my normal Azure subscription. But when I use a CSP account ,I get the below error :

*Cannot open backup device 'https://.blob.core.windows.net//.bak'. Operating system error 86(The specified network password is not correct.).*

Any help on fixing this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Following the steps below you should be able to get the file-list.
First you need to create a 'credential': e.g.

```
create credential [cmbackupprd-sqlbackup] 
with 
      identity = '<storageaccountname>', 
      secret = 'long-and-lengthy-storageaccountkey'
```

Now you can use this credential to connect to your storage-account.

```
restore filelistonly
from URL = 'https://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/backup.bak'
with credential='storageaccount-credential'
```

Note, I'm asssuming the backup is made directly from sql to azure blob-storage. Otherwise you might need to check the blob-type.